# Find parents where all children have the same value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am experiencing difficulties wrapping my head around this query.

Let's say we have 3 tables which look like this:

```
company
    id int IDENTITY,
    name nvarchar(255)

location
    id int IDENTITY,
    name nvarchar(255),
    company int

address
    id int IDENTITY,
    name nvarchar(255),
    location int
```

Please ignore keys and indexes for this usecase.

I want to return a list of companies where all of its child locations have an assigned address, and that address is the same across all of locations under that company.

**Example working data:**

```
select c.name, l.name, a.name
from company as c
join location as l on l.company = c.id
left join address as a on a.location = l.id



company     location          address
----------  ----------------  -----------------
3-DOM       Ankh-Morpork      Street 1
Adrenalize  Cabot Cove        Avenue 2
Adrenalize  Mayberry          Road 49
InterBlurb  Hogsmeade         NULL
InterBlurb  Kakariko Village  Alleyway 13
Octocore    Nibelheim         Blueberry Creek 2
Octocore    Mos Eisley        Blueberry Creek 2
```

**Example result:**

```
company   
----------
3-DOM     
Octocore
```

How would I go about achieving this result? I've tried grouping by `l.company` and selecting `count(distinct a.name)` and stuff but I can't seem to get the hang of it. An explanation with your query would be greatly appreciated, I need to understand this.

Comment: It's not clear to me where the parent-child relationship is being defined here.  Why is `Adrenalize` being excluded from your desired result set?

Comment: See the paragraph above the example working data: `and that address is the same across all of locations under that company.`. The locations under `Adrenalize` have different addresses, hence that company should be excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try grouping by the company name and retaining only those companies whose address is the same across all locations (this is what the inner query does):

```
WITH the_cte (companyName, locationName, address)
AS
(
    SELECT c.name, l.name, a.name
    FROM company AS c
    INNER JOIN location AS l
        ON l.company = c.id
    LEFT JOIN address AS a
        ON a.location = l.id
)

SELECT companyName, locationName, address
FROM the_cte
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT companyName, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN address IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
    FROM the_cte
    GROUP BY companyName
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN address IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 1
) t
    ON the_cte.companyName = t.companyName
```

Comment: Will not the `count` of the having-clause in the inner query yield `true` even if some address names are `NULL`?

Comment: Even if we used a `count(distinct(coalesce(a.name, '')))`, I wouldn't know how to know if a count of 1 means that all values are `''` or an address

Comment: Use a `CASE WHEN` expression to assign `NULL` a count value of zero.

Comment: That inner query is exactly what I need. Thanks alot Tim!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name 
FROM (
                SELECT        company.name
                FROM            company INNER JOIN
                                         location ON company.id = location.company LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                         address ON location.id = address.location
                GROUP BY company.name
                )sub

WHERE Name NOT IN (
                SELECT        company.name
                FROM            company INNER JOIN
                                         location ON company.id = location.company LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                         address ON location.id = address.location
                WHERE        (address.location IS NULL)
                GROUP BY company.name

                UNION

                SELECT        company.name
                FROM            location INNER JOIN
                                         address ON location.id = address.location INNER JOIN
                                         company ON location.company = company.id
                GROUP BY company.name
                HAVING        (COUNT(DISTINCT address.name) >1 )

                )
```

1. With the outer select query we combine the 3 sql queries
2. First query gets all company name
3. second query gets comapnies that doesnt have addresses
4. third query gets companies that have more than 1 different location